One Login Authentication Exception
I'm using oneLogin authentication in my Kotlin app. I tried with 2 different mobile phones and it works but when i try in a PDA with Android 10 Android the app crash with an exception :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1632)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1672)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:341)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:306)
    at com.onelogin.oidc.login.SignInManagerImpl.removeFragmentIfAttached(SignInManagerImpl.kt:74)
    at com.onelogin.oidc.login.SignInManagerImpl.signIn(SignInManagerImpl.kt:40)
    at com.onelogin.oidc.login.SignInManagerImpl$signIn$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:231)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:187)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:159)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:470)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:504)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:493)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:364)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel$BufferedChannelIterator.tryResumeHasNextOnClosedChannel(BufferedChannel.kt:1714)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.resumeWaiterOnClosedChannel(BufferedChannel.kt:2181)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.resumeReceiverOnClosedChannel(BufferedChannel.kt:2168)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.cancelSuspendedReceiveRequests(BufferedChannel.kt:2161)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.completeClose(BufferedChannel.kt:1938)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosed(BufferedChannel.kt:2217)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosedForSend0(BufferedChannel.kt:2192)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosedForSend(BufferedChannel.kt:2189)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.completeCloseOrCancel(BufferedChannel.kt:1910)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.closeOrCancelImpl(BufferedChannel.kt:1803)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.close(BufferedChannel.kt:1762)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.SendChannel$DefaultImpls.close$default(Channel.kt:95)
    at com.onelogin.oidc.login.SignInFragment.onDestroy(SignInFragment.kt:47)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:3376)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroy(FragmentStateManager.java:812)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2988)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:346)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:258)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:283)
    at ui.Hilt_MainActivity.onDestroy(Hilt_MainActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7403)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:39)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:498)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@51c581d, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]

My fragment is :
class OneLoginFragment : BaseFragment() {
    //binding
    private var _binding: FragmentOneLoginBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    var oidcClient: OIDCClient? = null

    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentOneLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initOneLogin()

        binding.btnSingIn.setOnClickListener {
            initOneLogin()
        }

        binding.btnLgout.setOnClickListener {
            logout()
        }
    }

    private fun logout() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "sign-out button clicked")

        Log.d("MainActivity", "initialized")
        try {
            oidcClient?.revokeToken(object : Callback<RevokeSuccess, RevokeError> {
                override fun onSuccess(success: RevokeSuccess) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "token: $success.sessionInfo.idToken");
                    binding.txtUser?.setText("");
                }

                override fun onError(error: RevokeError) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "message: $error.message");
                }
            })
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Error : ${ex.message}")
        }
    }

    private fun initOneLogin() {



        oidcClient = OneLoginOIDC.getClient()

        Log.d("MainActivity", "got client...")
        oidcClient?.signIn(activity as AppCompatActivity,
            object : Callback<SignInSuccess, SignInError> {
                override fun onSuccess(success: SignInSuccess) {
                    // The user has been authenticated successfully,
                    // the `success` param will contain the `SessionInfo` with the tokens ready to be used
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "token: $success.sessionInfo.idToken");
                    displayUserName(oidcClient)
                    //Log.d("MainActivity", success.sessionInfo)
                }

                override fun onError(loginError: SignInError) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        "message: ${loginError.message} : ${loginError.cause}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }
            });

    }

    fun displayUserName(oidcClient: OIDCClient?) {
        oidcClient?.getUserInfo(object : Callback<UserInfo, UserInfoError> {
            override fun onSuccess(success: UserInfo) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "${success.name} : ${success}")
                binding.txtUser.text = "${success.name}"
            }

            override fun onError(error: UserInfoError) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "info error")
            }
        })
    }
}

Why is this happening? I don't know what i have to do because only happens in my PDA with Android 10. I'm not navigating in this fragment. To navigate I have other graph with all destinations.

This question is similar to: getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"I've already tried what this post suggests, overriding the onSaveInstanceState method by removing the call to super, and it still crashes."
